# Is there a way to disable x11 clipboard in ssh environment?

Tags: linux, ssh, xorg, clipboard

I'm setting up a GUI environment for editing sensitive documents on a Linux server, by using ssh x11 forwarding to open up an editor remotely

Is there any way to prevent the contents of documents being copy/paste to the local computer, let's say by disabling the clipboard on every ssh connection? The setting has to be on the server.

Comment: OP here: I may have found a possible solution by using Xpra, it has an option of disabling clipboard forwarding, is it the solution for me?

Comment: You also have to disable screenshot+Tesseract on the local computer.